# TYPO3: HTML template on multiple pages

Tags: typo3

I have installed TYPO3 and am working with a HTML template and markers to display content.

There is only one thing i am asking myself:
I have several pages with the same layout but different content and I only want to change parts of these contents.

Do I have to implement a specific template for every page to make this work or is there any other way?

[image: Page one]
[image: Page two]
(the red marked content shall be changed only)

I hope you got the point what I want to achieve and can answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

there is a bootstrap introduction package that you can install (look at packages in the extension module)

https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/introduction

based on:
https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/bootstrap_package

there is no need for gridelements or DCE.
when you are a TYPO3 beginner, the introduction package gives you a good start because it stays close tho the TYPO3 'core' way of creating a website.

After you have learned how to create basic templates (with backend layouts & FLUIDTEMPLATES) you can deep into other extension like DCE or gridelements.

Comment: thanks for answering!
Do you mean HTML templating? Thats what i am working with!

Answer (score 0):

You can either create a template for each page or use one template for the whole content and then use some other extensions to create the grid view.

For this job the best extensions are:
dce - dynamic content element [dce extensions](https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/dce)
     -- or --
gridelements  [gridelements extension](https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/gridelements)

Comment: thanks for the fast answer!
what would you suggest me in my case? its a static webpage with about 10 pages (with bootstrap framework).

Comment: I can suggest you to check out gridelements for building a bootstrap grid layout